# Как сделать условный вид сверху у фотографии?

Tags: html5, изображения, photoshop

Добрый день! Я делаю небольшую 2д игру на `HTML5` и у меня есть такое изображение:
[image]

Тут изображена пушка на колёсиках, но если вы заметили, то пушка немного наклонена вперёд, то есть такое ощущение, что она уткнулась в в пол. На `HTML5` канвасе это особенно заметно. Можно ли как-то сделать у этой картинки вид сверху или как-то повернуть её, чтобы смотрелось красивее? Смотрел в интернете по этому поводу, но ничего полезного не нашёл, смотрел по всем инструментам `Adobe Photoshop`, но там тоже ничего для моей цели нет. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать по принципу camera mapping, например, в cinema4D. Т.е. спроецировать изображение на простые 3d объекты (цилиндр, куб), а потом вывести вид сверху. Но это слишком сложный вариант для такой задачи, да и графика небольшого разрешения. Поэтому проще будет вручную попытаться в фотошопе избавиться от деталей которые указывают на вид сбоку.

[image: вид сверху]

Вроде того.

И можно еще добавить полупрозрачную тень в одну сторону, тогда еще больше будет похоже на вид сверху

Comment: понятно, буду знать. постараюсь повторить эту картинку в фотошопе, или возьму эту. спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Вам придется ее перерисовывать.

Это картинка объемной модели и по такому виду сбоку вы не получите информации о том как она выглядит сверху.